# How do I attach a full resolution photo?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail, attachment

When attaching photos using Google Inbox, if I use the paperclip button to attach multiple photos, it seems that Inbox resizes them to about 512 pixels wide.

How can I stop Inbox from shrinking my photos?

Comment: I'm too struggling with this issue now. It seems that the web version of Inbox displays smaller versions of the attached images, but when I open the same sent email from the Inbox app on android, and tap on the images, they appear in their original resolution.

Comment: I think that it's been shrinking them on the browser version when you view, but when you download them with the button, it gives you the full resolution image.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because Inbox by Gmail was retired in April, 2019

Answer (score 1):

You could zip it before attaching.

I prefer [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to compress all my documents and photos before attaching.